# Extracting words from string

Tags: apache-spark

I have a dataframe. I have a column which is having a statement for example "Worked for 25 days in In ABC Company". All i need to extract "25 days" and put it in new column. I am using scala with spark. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have to extract this specific pattern?

Comment: Hi  EmiCareOfCell44 , Yes I need to extract only days from the particular column on the dataframe with new column extracted days

Answer (score 1):

```
df.withColumn("working_days", regexp_extract(col("statement"), """\d* days?""", 0))
  .where(length(col("working_days")) > 0)
```

Comment: Thanks dre-hh...almost worked  but unable to extract ""25 days"" from "Worked for 25 days in In ABC Company"

Comment: @Shakthi Prasad try with this regex `(\d+\sdays)`